# how to stop looper.loop() in Android Multithreading program?

Tags: android, multithreading, gps

Currently, I am trying to develop an Android application. Application reads Location data from `GPS` first(thru `onLocationUpdates(GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0 , Listener)` and if `GPS` is not able to retrieve data in specific time ( in my case 5 sec ),it again asks to `Network provider` ( thru `onLocationUpdates(NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, Listener)` ).

In my program I have handled this task as follows.

```
mWorker = new WorkerThread();
mWorker.start(); //  Thread creation and Calling run() Method 

class WorkerThread extends Thread{      
public void run() {   
try {    
if(isGPSEnabled){   

 //Call GPS_PROVIDER for Location updates,
 //Will get location value in Location Change Listener

 requestLocationUpdates(GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,Listener);
Log.d(TAG,"GPS Listener is  registered and thread is going for Sleep");
Thread.sleep(THREAD_SLEEP_TIME);

}else if (isNetworkEnbles){
// if  GPS_PROVIDER is not available, will call to NETWORK_PROVIDER 
// Will get location value to OnLocationChangeListener

 requestLocationUpdates(NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,listener);
 Log.d(TAG,"NETWORK Listener is  registered and thread is going for Sleep");
Thread.sleep(THREAD_SLEEP_TIME);
}
} catch ( InterruptedException e ){ 
   // Thread is interrupted on OnLocationChange Listener
  // Thread has been Interrupted, It means.. data is available thru Listener.

}
// Thread had sleep for THREAD_SLEEP_TIME , but Still data is not available
If (GPS or Network data isnt available thru GPS listener or Network Listener ) {
   // Do try for one more time.

}
}
```

Now My OnLocationChanged Listener code as Follows:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 

// Listener got location 
// First Intrupt the sleeping Thread
mWorker.interrupt();

if ( loc != null )
{
  //get Location
}

}
```

Now  **my problem is** , when I run this code , Worker Thread never calls `OnLocationChanged` Listener.

I have inserted  `looper.Loop()` in worker thread , `OnLocationChanged` is called. But it runs continuously and `looper` not get stop. How should I stop `looper.loop()`?

Is there any ***other*** way  thru which I can manage  my above task except `workerThread.`
If you need more clarification, just let me know.

Comment: Why do you want to run this in a separate thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Thread.sleep() on the main thread.  You are blocking it from running.  There is no need to have a separate thread for what you are doing, you just need to allow your main thread to continue running so that you can handle the events through your callbacks as they are received.